# list all tables in mysql with serial number

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to list all the tables in a database with serial number, something like this

```
+-------+---------------------------------------+
| sl_no | table_name                            |
+-------+---------------------------------------+
|     0 | aaaaccadminprofile                    |
|     0 | aaaaccbadloginstatus                  |
|     0 | aaaacchttpsession                     |
|     0 | aaaaccoldpassword                     |
|     0 | aaaaccount                            |
|     0 | aaaaccountowner                       |
|     0 | aaaaccountstatus                      |
|     0 | aaaaccownerprofile                    |
|     0 | aaaaccpassword                        |
|     0 | aaaaccsession                         |
|     0 | aaaaccsessionaudit                    |
|     0 | aaaaccsessionprop                     |
|     0 | aaaaccuserprofile                     |
```

and I tried this code

```
select @a:=0 as sl_no, table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'eventlog';
```

but I don't know where to increment the value, it shows only 0. adding (@a:=@a+1) shows error.
Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
set @a=0;
select (@a:=@a + 1) as sl_no, table_name 
   from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'eventlog';
```

Comment: You used `,` :(

Comment: @MatBailie, thank u Sir - modified the answer